# AWS SWF API call logging for Ruby Flow framework

Tags: ruby, logging, amazon-web-services

So I need to be able to see the logs for each decider and activity start with what it was given and how it failed, etc

I am familiar with [THIS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/ct-logging.html) document but that only allows mw to see registrations and deprecations, I need the internals to be logged and to be able to see them... I am using Ruby and the flow framework. I have scoured the docs and cannot find anything.... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, after many MANY hours of searching and scouring the source code, I appear to have answered my own question. You need to pass in a logger when you run an activity or decider as follows:

```
some_decider_class.new(swf_domain.client, swf_domain, worker_class.task_list, worker_class) { { use_forking: false, logger: logger } }
```

You can also provide it as part of the AWS module while configuring the SDK.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, can you describe your solution in more depth. I dont see how you are passing in a logger?