# Logging to an external service with aws-flow

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, logging

I'm using aws-flow to interact with Amazon's Simple Workflow Server and I want to get logging set up to go to an external source (PaperTrail).

I've set my `$logger` to use PaperTrail and I pass this into the client I use to start the execution;

```
client = Aws::SWF::Client.new(region: 'eu-west-1', logger: $logger)
client.start_workflow_execution({
    domain: domain,
    workflow_id: ...,
    workflow_type: {
      name: "...",
      version: ...
    },
    task_list: {
      name: "..."
    }
  })
```

This successfully logs that the client has started, but no action from inside a Workflow or Activity gets logged.

From reading the documentation and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475739/aws-swf-api-call-logging-for-ruby-flow-framework) it seems like you need to specify a logger when creating new Activities, but I can't see how to do that.

The main workflow uses `activity_client` to select the Activitiy it needs, and the activity being called looks like;

```
class MyActivity
  extend AWS::Flow::Activities
  activity :my_activity do {
   default_task_list: '...',
   version: ...,
   default_task_schedule_to_start_timeout: 60,
   default_task_start_to_close_timeout: 60,
   exponential_retry: { maximum_attempts: 2 }
}
```

I can't see anywhere with this setup that you can add a logger to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out aws-flow [doesn't support logging](https://github.com/aws/aws-flow-ruby/blob/master/aws-flow/lib/aws/runner.rb#L184).

There is some chat about it in issues and there is a [PR](https://github.com/aws/aws-flow-ruby/pull/111/files) which appears to fix things.

For my needs I just forked the project (which at the time of writing hasn't been updated in 2 years) and made the relevant changes for me.